# How could I scan text file line by line using cuda c programming

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing

I need to scan a text file and use the string for processing parallel. I need to know file reading and writing is possible in cuda c programming.If possible what are the keywords can be used. I used "File" but it gives undefined.

I using the visual studio 2013.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the host filesystem from `__global__` or `__device__` functions.  What you would want to do is read and parse the file with `fopen`, `fgets`, etc in a host function, copy the data to the device and then do your parallel processing on it.